# Pipeline trigger doesn't run because it's getting the wrong branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Friends how to make Run Pipeline get the desired branch by default.
My trigger is not being fired because in the pipeline execution it is looking for the yml file that does not exist in the master branch, I want it to automatically load branch feat-regression-test.

```
my yaml file

trigger:
- feat-regression-test

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: UseRubyVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>= 2.5'

- script: |
    gem install bundler
    bundle install --retry=3 --jobs=4
  displayName: 'bundle install'

- script: bundle exec cucumber -t @incluir_setor_resp_em_branco
  displayName: 'bundle exec cucumber'


- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'NUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    mergeTestResults: true
    searchFolder: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)'
    testRunTitle: 'Regression Test Geocall Gab'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abXfC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this syntax :

```
 trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - feat-regression-test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the pipeline's default branch by editing the pipeline definition via the UI and going to the "Triggers" section. There will be a "YAML" tab where you can configure this behavior.

[image]